# modify SVN change log

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, changelog

I'm using VisualSVN and tortoise to work with an SVN repository.  Someone needed some folders moved from one location to a new location in the same repostiory.  I goofed up though and just copy/pasted the old folders into the new location (didn't get the change history, etc).  Since then they have updated a bunch of the files.  The old files (from the previous location) weren't deleted or anything.  Is there a way to get the change history from the old files and associate it with the new location?  I would need to add revision numbers, log messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back and recopy the old files, at first you will then not have the changes associated with the new files. However, you can then merge the changes in.

So, yes, you can probably get what you want by moving or deleting the new files, then copying the old files (with history) to the new location, and then merging the changes that you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Not tracking the full history of a file across moves/renames a known failing of SVN. If you really need this type of functionality, you'd be better off with something like git or Mercurial.

And yes, I'm aware that many times migrating to a new VCS isn't really an option. Unfortunately it means that when you run up against something like this, you're pretty much stuck.

Comment: -1: The question did not indicate that an svn move or svn rename was used.

Comment: -1: Since when is not tracking file history a known failing of SVN? Maybe you are thinking of some other VCS?

Comment: The question clearly implies that the poster "goofed up" by using a copy/paste instead of an svn move / svn rename. Subversion is well known for losing file history if a file is renamed or moved by the OS instead of via the corresponding Subversion command.

Comment: The answer implies that tracking a file across moves/renames is something that SVN doesn't do, as opposed to Mercurial and Git. I'm pretty sure that Mercurial, at least, like SVN, needs to be told when a file is moved or copied, and doesn't deduce this on its own. I'm not sure it has any advantage on SVN here. Git does, since it has its own algorithms for figuring out a file history.